# Emulate a C++ Enum in Java

Tags: java, c++, enums, emulation

I want to translate this C++ code into Java code

```
#include <iostream>
enum {ADD=1, ERASE, MODIFY, EXIT};
int main() {
    int option;
    cin>>option;
    switch(option){
    case ADD: //do something . . .
         break;
    case ERASE: //do things . . .
    default:
```

I'm lost with Java Enums because I can't get them to work like this.

Comment: Which part isn't working? What do you mean you "can't get them to work"?

Comment: There is a nice example in the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Java enums are objects, they're not bound to `int` values.

Comment: Post your Java code that isnt working & explain the problem

Comment: My guess is that your problem is the `=1` syntax. You probably shouldn't be defining the actual enum values in Java.

Comment: @Kyle Strand Which probably also hints at another reason why it is not working: the '=1' would shift the enum int values in C++ by 1... In Java you'd need to compare the input with the ordinal() of the enum object/instance and account for the offset manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, enumeration are *objects*, and a enumeration creates a *new type*.

```
enum MyEnum {
    ADD, ERASE, MODIFY, EXIT;
}
```

So `MyEnum.ADD` is of type `MyEnum`, etc. This allows for powerful OO programming -- encapsulation, inheritance -- with enumerations.

If you want to convert a `int` to a `MyEnum`, you can write a method to do that, or use the index of the enum.

```
MyEnum.values()[1];
```

---

If you just want to have constants that use an existing type (such as `int`), just do

```
class MyConstants {
    public final static int ADD = 1;
    public final static int ERASE = 2;
    public final static int MODIFY = 3;
    public final static int EXIT = 4;
}
```

This is actually the closest to your C++ example.

Answer (score 1):

In java enums are objects, not ints. This means they can have behaviours rather than merely representing a value. So ideally the behaviour of each enum value should be encapsulated inside the enum itself:

```
enum Operation {
    ADD {
        public void perform() {
            // do something
        }
    },
    ERASE {
        public void perform() {
            // do something else
        }
    },
    ...

    abstract public void perform();
}

Operation.values()[option].perform();
```